# Was Golden Age Superman (1938 - 1955) able to see through women's clothes with his x-ray vision?

Tags: dc, superman

I can't think of an incident when [Golden Age](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Age) superman was able to see people naked.

I wonder how Lois would have felt about it if it was possible

Comment: "an indecent" hehe.

Comment: Silver age; http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2356/a4d020c202257a6e44332c4.jpg

Answer (score 7):

This cover from Superboy (aka young Superman) demonstrates that he is capable to see through layers of clothes, at least when worn by another male. There is no reason to believe that he could not also see through women's clothing when he would want to. But considering that Superman follows a very strong code of ethics, it would be very unlikely that he would abuse this power for his own sexual pleasure (and besides, the censors of that time wouldn't have allowed it anyway).

[image]

Comment: OP asks about Golden Age Superman. The cover is from [1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_Boy), however, the Golden Age ended in the [early 50s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Comic_Books).

Comment: Agreed. Although this is interesting, it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: "*and besides, the censors of that time wouldn't have allowed it anyway*".  This is the **real** answer: just ignore inconvenient questions.  The readers will fill in the blanks and keep on reading.